# Can not execute query using PHP where the same query work fine in phpmyadmin

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to delete rows from a table...I' using this code:

```js
$query = "Delete from usertour where tourID = $idnum and name LIKE '%$session%' ";
```

And it never deleted the row either if the idnum and session is correct

I tried to execute the same query in phpmyadmin this way:

```js
Delete from usertour where tourID = 1 and name LIKE '%test@hotmail.com%'
```

When I executed like this it works...the problem is probably in this part '%$session%', I tried to fixed but I can't.

Any help?

[image]

here is some database...I connected to right db  because I use php and mysql in several places except this...and the problem is only in '%$session%'...everything else is working well, and it execute the query but can not match the name filed.

If I output the $idnum, $session and the $query variables I' getting this:

[image]

Comment: `Variables` in `single-quotes` are — not — read. Only `""`.

Comment: @AjAX. if you don't know what are you talking about - __do not__ comment.

Comment: Can you show where you execute the query (in PHP)

Comment: It doesn matter if it is " " or ' '....you have only to know with which you start the query

Comment: @NigelRen you mean that you want the code of executing that query from my php file?

Comment: Somewhere you must call something like mysqli_query, or `query()` - this code would be useful.

Comment: $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

Comment: Does `$result` come back as true or false (if false, there is an error and you should log/output it).  Also, please don't use `@` to suppress errors, they happen for a reason (and don't happen when your code works properly).

Comment: the $result return TRUE..so  it execute the query...but the problem is in '%$session%'

Comment: That query should execute, so the problem most likely lies in the surrounding code. Also, why are you wildcards?

Comment: Check `$session` for any "invisible" characters like HTML tags and such.

Comment: Unhelpfully you posted a screenshot of your output, instead of pasting it, but is there a space between your % and the "t" of test in that? Or perhaps some other character which the webpage might render as a space? And the same between the last "m" and the last %? It _looks_ visually like there might be. If there is, that would cause it not to match. Try trimming your $session variable of whitespace before using it. Also there seems to be no particular need for LIKE here since you're matching the whole field. You can just use = .

Comment: And I strongly advise you to start using parameterised queries and prepared statements, to protect yourself against SQL injection attacks - especially if either of your variable values is taken from user input. This will help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: @ADyson idnum = 1 session = test@hotmail.com query:Delete from usertour where tourID = 1 and name LIKE '% test@hotmail.com %' here is the code...I tried before to trim it but don't help...

Comment: perhaps it's not really a whitespace character, perhaps it's actually some HTML or newline or other unprintable character. Check the page source instead of the browser display. Anyway, apart from the security vulnerability there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted, you need to fix your input data.

Comment: @ADyson I got this from the html source....idnum =  1 session =   test@hotmail.com   query:Delete from usertour where tourID =  1  and name LIKE '%  test@hotmail.com   %' Deleted

Comment: Well there's _something_ in there. If it's whitespace, `trim($session)` should sort it out.

Comment: Try `$query = "Delete from usertour where tourID = $idnum and name LIKE '%".trim($session)."%' ";`

Comment: I tried use trim($session) but now I got new idea of using it, so I will try to do

Comment: @ADyson I fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have added spaces to the $session variable according to your picture.

Also, according to you examples you don't need to use LIKE and wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to do this is with prepared statements. The way these play out varies slightly depending on what database driver layer you're using (`mysqli` vs PDO) but looks generally like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM usertour WHERE tourID=? AND name=?");
```

Where you then *bind* the two values on before executing that query. Note that `name=?` is used here specifically because `LIKE` is for *close enough* situations, something you do not want here. If using `LIKE` then you'll delete `name@example.com` as well as `name@example.com.au`, two completely different email addresses.

> If you have spaces in your email field that you're using `LIKE` to ignore that's a dirty data problem and you must clean up your data. Don't make the situation worse by layering in hacks such as `LIKE`.

If you have spaces in your input for whatever reason, get rid of them prior to executing the query using the [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function:

```
$session = trim($session);
```

When executing the query you'll do something like this for `mysqli`:

```
$stmt->bind_param("is", $idnum, $session);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or this for PDO:

```
$stmt->execute([ $idnum, $session ]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try by escaping the session variable as per your sql driver. MySQL Example below.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `usertour` WHERE `tourID` = '".$idnum."' AND `name` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($session)."%' ";
```

Comment: $query don't produce anything because it can match the $session with the table field name...even if they are the same

Comment: can you print the $query variable so that we can see what is being executed?

Comment: if I only print the $query variable with echo "query = " . $query it will output this : query:Delete from usertour where tourID = 1 and name LIKE '% test@hotmail.com %'

Comment: can you var_dump the $session variable and check the string length. for test@hotmail.com it should be 16.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated. Did you mean mysqli_real_escape_string?

Comment: @akshaykhairmode here is it : length=21...why you think it should be 16?

Comment: @ADyson I used mysqli_... but don't help

Comment: @AbuMachi that comment wasn't directed at you, it was directed at Akshay who posted the answer. I never said it would help or not, I merely don't want people posting answers containing code which is discontinued for security reasons.

Comment: @ADyson 

Try by escaping the session variable as per your sql driver. MySQL Example below. This is what i wrote since i dont know what he uses. I have written as per your sql driver

Comment: @AbuMachi test@hotmail.com is 16 characters string

Comment: @akshaykhairmode well you should assume for a start he's not using something which was discontinued in 2013 (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)... and also it's mentioned in the comments on the main question that mysqli is being used, which was posted 10 minutes before you posted your answer....

Comment: there is whitespaces...because of that it output 21...but now I solve it..thanks anyway

Answer (score -2):

[image]
php will transform your sentence to mysql
    so you can try this :
    $query = "Delete from usertour where tourID = $idnum and name LIKE %{$session}% ";

Comment: Please learn about [PHP string interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) before making comments like this. Switching from `"$x"` to `"{$x}"` changes *nothing*.

Comment: this misses the point of the problem which was shown in the comments already when you posted your answer